# applets in system tray in arch linux gnome desktop

Tags: linux, arch-linux, gnome, tray

Apps don't display applets in the system tray, as they do on Ubuntu. I am using gnome with Arch Linux.

Apps such as telegram, OBS, VLC, etc should show a small applet in the top bar, to easily access the apps.

How do I make them appear again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install the ["Tray Icons" gnome shell extension](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1503/tray-icons/) and then reboot your system.